# air + iOS: what is the difference between iPad1 and iPad2

Tags: ios, air

I'm have an AIR app which works on iPad1, but it cannot be even installed on iPad2 (app is deployed via iTunes). There shown something like "failed to install APPID" on iPad. The problem is that I don't have an iPad2, so I can't test.

What is the difference between instalation on iPad1 and iPad2 that can cause the problem?

**PS:** Here's a command used to build ipa:

```
adt -package -target ipa-debug -connect -storetype pkcs12 -keystore ******.p12 
-storepass ****** -provisioning-profile p.mobileprovision app.ipa
application.xml app.swf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. I would guess that your issue is to do with a missing or incorrect UDID number for the iPad2 within your provisioning profile.

Comment: I'd checked that numerous times!