# Adobe Air app installs at ipad 1 but doesn't on Ipad 3

Tags: ios, ipad, air, adobe, ipad-3

We have an air app which works on ipad 1. But when we try to install it on Ipad 3 it fails to install our app (saying useless message). But it is possible to install another apps on this Ipad. We have Adobe Air 3.2 SDK. App.xml config is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0">
<id>com.comapping.ipad</id>
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
<publisherID>................................</publisherID>
<filename>Comapping</filename>
<name>Comapping</name>
<description>.........................</description>
<copyright>Copyright (c) 2010 Comapping A/S</copyright>
<initialWindow>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <title>Comapping</title>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <content>comapping.swf</content>
    <renderMode>cpu</renderMode>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
</initialWindow>
<installFolder>Comapping Desktop</installFolder>
<programMenuFolder>Comapping Desktop</programMenuFolder>
<icon>
    <image72x72>icons/application-72.png</image72x72>
    <image48x48>icons/application-48.png</image48x48>
</icon>
<fileTypes>
    <fileType>
        <name>Comapping</name>
        <extension>comap</extension>
        <description>Comapping Document</description>
        <contentType>text/xml</contentType>
    </fileType>
    <fileType>
        <name>Comapping</name>
        <extension>meadmap</extension>
        <description>Comapping Document</description>
        <contentType>text/xml</contentType>
    </fileType>
</fileTypes>
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <string>2</string>
            </array>
        ]]>
    </InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I've found error log

```
Jul 17 16:15:54 unknown installd[699] <Error>: 0038a000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620395
Jul 17 16:15:54 unknown installd[699] <Error>: 0038a000 preflight_application_install:     Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.KjzWxA/foo_extracted/Payload/Comapping.app
```

Comment: @Wooble Yes, I'm sure that error message "Application failed to install" is useless.

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928557/air-ios-what-is-the-difference-between-ipad1-and-ipad2